# Mysql join not showing results

Tags: sql, dreamweaver

Trying to get two tables to show data in a table.

Table 1 (suppliers) has all supplier details
Table 2 (repdetails) has details of all our reps and agents

Table 1 and Table 2 both have RepID columns

Here's the SQL query:

```
SELECT suppliers.ID, suppliers.Suppliername, suppliers.postcode, suppliers.address, suppliers.phone, suppliers.fax, suppliers.email, suppliers.website, suppliers.Active, suppliers.imagename, suppliers.RepID, repdetails.RepID, repdetails.RepName, repdetails.RepEmail, repdetails.RepPhone 
FROM suppliers 
JOIN repdetails 
ON suppliers.RepID = repdetails.RepID
```

[The blank fields show where the data should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EVQU.png)

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you have no `suppliers.RepID = repdetails.RepID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting from Supliers, have you tried a LEFT join? Im not sure how your db looks like and if this is useful for your goals

```
SELECT 
    suppliers.`ID`, 
    suppliers.`Suppliername`, 
    suppliers.`postcode`, 
    suppliers.`address`, 
    suppliers.`phone`, 
    suppliers.`fax`, 
    suppliers.`email`, 
    suppliers.`website`, 
    suppliers.`Active`, 
    suppliers.`imagename`, 
    suppliers.`RepID`, 
    repdetails.`RepID`, 
    repdetails.`RepName`, 
    repdetails.`RepEmail`, 
    repdetails.`RepPhone` 
FROM suppliers 
LEFT JOIN repdetails ON suppliers.`RepID` = repdetails.`RepID`
```

Also you are selecting `RepID` twice. If you need this info in your results, you can try

```
    suppliers.`RepID` as s_repid,
    repdetails.`RepID` as r_repid,
```

But maybe you just wanna remove these  rows or keep 1?

Comment: Selecting the same field twice does not "overwrite", you'll get two fields with the same name (but the correct values) in your resultset.  If  you're accessing fields by index, you'll never notice.  If you're doing it by name, then you'll get frustrated.

Comment: Actually, it did when I started the code from scratch.